# How to use YouTube API OAuth 2.0 in Google Colab?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-colaboratory, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to use YouTube Data API in Google Colab for retrieve the results of a search.

I'm using the [code available in the documentation](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/search.py) as a blueprint.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# This sample executes a search request for the specified search term.
# Sample usage:
#   python search.py --q=surfing --max-results=10
# NOTE: To use the sample, you must provide a developer key obtained
#       in the Google APIs Console. Search for "REPLACE_ME" in this code
#       to find the correct place to provide that key..

import argparse

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


# Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps
# tab of
#   https://cloud.google.com/console
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
DEVELOPER_KEY = 'REPLACE_ME'
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = 'v3'

def youtube_search(options):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

  # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
  # query term.
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=options.q,
    part='id,snippet',
    maxResults=options.max_results
  ).execute()

  videos = []
  channels = []
  playlists = []

  # Add each result to the appropriate list, and then display the lists of
  # matching videos, channels, and playlists.
  for search_result in search_response.get('items', []):
    if search_result['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video':
      videos.append('%s (%s)' % (search_result['snippet']['title'],
                                 search_result['id']['videoId']))
    elif search_result['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#channel':
      channels.append('%s (%s)' % (search_result['snippet']['title'],
                                   search_result['id']['channelId']))
    elif search_result['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#playlist':
      playlists.append('%s (%s)' % (search_result['snippet']['title'],
                                    search_result['id']['playlistId']))

  print 'Videos:\n', '\n'.join(videos), '\n'
  print 'Channels:\n', '\n'.join(channels), '\n'
  print 'Playlists:\n', '\n'.join(playlists), '\n'


if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--q', help='Search term', default='Google')
  parser.add_argument('--max-results', help='Max results', default=25)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  try:
    youtube_search(args)
  except HttpError, e:
    print 'An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

However, when executing this code, I got this message on the console:

> Please visit this URL to authorize this application:
> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=327114017303-uvhp1oeqmuvsjohr0bmjevcet3g6tsb6.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.readonly+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube.force-ssl&state=qUtm4Dd4xh7NPerHBdf8bsEP3yoae2&prompt=consent&access_type=offline

I clicked on the link, but, the page shows this message/error:

> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
> The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient

Screenshot:

[image: error_400]

I'm unable to find any documentation or tutorial that shows how to use OAuth 2.0 in Google Colab.

I find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41003429/12511801) - which use the Google OAuth 2.0 Playground -, but, nothing related to Google Colab and the Error 400 - which I *think* it's about the IPs/permissons to set on the API_KEY about certains domains.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12710262/12511801) and I checked and tried the answers made there, but, the problem persist, I'm stating to believe that it's not possible to use OAuth 2.0 with Google Colab - I hope I'm wrong on this case...

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67632908/12511801) says:

> To fix you issue, you'll have to have the same redirect URI set on your project within Google developers console and, at the same time, within your Python script.

I have added the domain of Google Colaboratory and the error continues. Does anybody knows the correct steps for solvie this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the developer key and replace like how it says here to authorize the API connection like highlighted in this section:

```
# Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps
# tab of
#   https://cloud.google.com/console
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your 
project.
DEVELOPER_KEY = 'REPLACE_ME'
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = 'v3'
```